# Can't get the data in viewbag

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, viewbag

From a View, I am trying to access the data assigned to Viewbag in Controller. Here is what I tried so far:

#### The View:

```
@model SPES_PPS.Models.Benificiary

<h3>My partial view</h3>

<table>

@foreach (var item in ViewBag.bendetails)
{
    <tr>
        <td>Beni ID</td>
        <td>@item.benID</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
}


</table>
```

#### The Controller

```
   // GET: Benificiary/Details/
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {       
   Benificiary benificiary = db.Benificiaries.Find(id);
                if (benificiary == null)
                {
  return HttpNotFound();
                }
   ViewBag.bendetails = benificiary;
                return PartialView("Partial_Details", benificiary);

        }
    }
```

But it is not working, how can I get the data in Viewbag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can directly access data from model like @Model.itemName

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In your Action, You return a PartialView with a model, Why you get data from `ViewBag`?

You use `db.xxx.Find(id)` to select a Benificiary, Why you use `foreach()`?

You can try to change your code like in Partial view.

```
@model SPES_PPS.Models.Benificiary

<h3>My partial view</h3>

<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Beni ID</td>
            <td>@Model.benID</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>    
    
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing `beneficiary` object to view which accepts an object of the same type, you can access it in your View as the following:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.benID)
```

or

```
@Model.benID
```

However, if you want to use ViewBag to pass data from Controller to View, use ViewDate.

In Controller,

```
ViewData["beneficiary"] = benificiary;
```

In View, the assigned data will be string, so you need to cast it to `beneficiary` object

```
@{
    var beneficiary = ViewData["beneficiary"] as Beneficiary;
}
<span>@beneficiary.benID</span>
```